# How can I browse public games in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Could someone show the process for browsing public games on Diablo 3 on the PC (via screen shots), as I have been trying for a while and cannot find it. I can locate the choose Chat and choose Clan. But this is all.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot browse public games. If you choose 'public game' in the preferences you will automatically join a public game suiting your difficulty settings chosen by the system.

Answer (score 6):

Just as @dgw says, you cannot browse public games.

When you choose "Public Game" and "Join" it uses the difficulty setting you currently have selected and the activity you currently have selected (Rifts, Greater Rifts, Bounties, etc) to drop you in queue to join another person's public game with those settings.

Once you've selected a difficulty and an activity, the number of players also using those criteria appears at the bottom of the Game Settings window. That's about as close as you can get to "browsing".

[image: Game Settings window]

Comment: It is not the number of rooms but the number of players if I remember that correctly.

Comment: @dgw Do you have a reference for this? I can't find anything saying one way or another.

Comment: @dgw It looks like from the in-game verbiage that you're correct, I'll edit my answer.